# I am wondering why I get a random integer as my output in this program

Tags: c

This program is designed to take 3 integers and arrange them in ascending order. When I input a combination such as "12 8 2", I get an output of "1995099040 8 12". Any help with why i'm getting this answer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findBig(int d, int e, int f) {
    if ((d >= e) && (d >= f)) {
        return d;
    } else
    if ((e >= d) && (e >= f)) {
        return e;
    } else
    if ((f >= e) && (f >= d)) {
        return f;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    const int MAX_NUM = 3;
    int userArray[MAX_NUM];
    int bigNum;
    int midNum;
    int smallNum;
    int j = 0;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    printf("Please enter three integers separated by spaces:\n");

    for (j = 0; j < MAX_NUM; ++j) {
        scanf("%d", &userArray[j]);
    }
    a = userArray[0];
    b = userArray[1];
    c = userArray[2];

    bigNum = findBig(a, b, c);

    if (bigNum == a) {
        midNum = findBig(0, b, c);
    } else
    if (bigNum == b) {
        midNum = findBig(a, 0, c);
    } else
    if (bigNum == c) {
        midNum = findBig(a, b, 0);
    }
    if ((midNum == a) && (bigNum == b)) {
        smallNum = c;
    } else
    if ((midNum == b) && (bigNum == c)) {
        smallNum = a;
    } else
    if ((midNum == c) && (bigNum == a)) {
        smallNum = b;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", smallNum, midNum, bigNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The strategy of reading numbers into an array is good, but everything after that is not a good way of working. You should probably just sort the array so you can pick the values out in the required order trivially. What you've got is more or less okay as an exercise in writing `if` statements, but otherwise leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 7):

`smallNum` stays with the junk value it gets when it is created, because you didn't cover all the cases for the values possible for `bigNum` and `midNum`, so it doesn't get assigned a value in certain cases - like the one you experienced the problem with - and stays uninitialized.

Make sure to check all the possible cases:

```
if((midNum == a) && (bigNum == b)){ smallNum = c; }
else if((midNum == b) && (bigNum == c)){ smallNum = a; }
else if((midNum == c) && (bigNum == a)){ smallNum = b; }
else if((midNum == b) && (bigNum == a)){ smallNum = c; }
else if((midNum == c) && (bigNum == b)){ smallNum = a; }
else if((midNum == a) && (bigNum == c)){ smallNum = b; }
```

---

Also, consider using built-in functions, to save time and code - you have the `max` and `min` function right there to help you.

To find the maximum of three numbers you may use `max(max(a, b), c)` - so we can shorten the code to

```
smallNum = min(min(a, b), c);
bigNum = max(max(a, b), c);
midNum = (a + b + c) - smallNum - bigNum;
```

(This will halve the code and render `findBig` unnecessary)

Comment: What language supports `max({a, b, c})`? Furthermore, `midNum = min(max(a, b), c);` fails to identify the correct number for `a=1, b=2, c=0`.

Comment: interesting alternative to determine `midNum`, but not completely OK: it invokes undefined behavior if `a + b + c` causes arithmetic overflow among other possibilities.

Comment: If you suspect the inputs provided will be large indeed, you can convert them to longs, apply this method, and rest assured of overflow issues (the result would be one of the original int anyways, so you need longs only for the operation)

Comment: Technically, converting to `long` or even `long long` does not exclude undefined behavior on architectures where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` or `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long long)`. There is a simple solution using unsigned arithmetics that is fully defined if `a`, `b` and `c` are non negative and implementation defined otherwise: `midNum = (unsigned)a + b + c - smallNum - bigNum;`

Comment: How about `(a - bigNum) + (b - smallNum) + c`? This should ensure no overflow during evaluation (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'm afraid not: `a = MIN_INT, b = MAX_INT, c = 0` invokes undefined behavior on both subtractions. Writing fully defined code for all Standard compliant architectures is a tricky game.

Comment: So how does assuming the numbers are unsigned solves the overflow?

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow, it is defined to wrap around. Casting `a` as `unsigned` causes the whole expression to compute using unsigned arithmetic, yielding the correct value as long as it is positive. If the middle value is negative, the result of the unsigned expression will be greater than `INT_MAX` and storing that to an `int` has an implementation defined effect.  On most architectures, it will produce the correct value in `midNum`, but the Standard allows another implementation defined behavior.  If all values are positive or zero, the unsigned expression full defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 cases to consider for determining smallNum.

```
if((midNum == a) && (bigNum == b) || ((midNum == b) && (bigNum == a))){
 smallNum = c; 
}
else if((midNum == b) && (bigNum == c) || ((midNum == c) && (bigNum == b))){
 smallNum = a; 
}
else if((midNum == c) && (bigNum == a) || ((midNum == a) && (bigNum == c))){ 
smallNum = b; 
}
```

The junk is due to the missing cases.

Answer (score 0):

You get garbage output because your code invokes undefined behavior:
for the input `12 8 2`, the case `(midNum == b) && (bigNum == a)` is not handled in the code and `smallNum` stays uninitialized.

You can simplify your code by rearranging the array with 3 tests and swaps:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int MAX_NUM = 3;
    int userArray[MAX_NUM];
    int x;

    printf("Please enter three integers separated by spaces:\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUM; ++j) {
        if (scanf("%d", &userArray[j]) != 1)
            exit(1);
    }
    if (userArray[0] > userArray[1]) {
        x = userArray[0]; userArray[0] = userArray[1]; userArray[1] = x;
    }
    if (userArray[1] > userArray[2]) {
        x = userArray[1]; userArray[1] = userArray[2]; userArray[2] = x;
    }
    if (userArray[0] > userArray[1]) {
        x = userArray[0]; userArray[0] = userArray[1]; userArray[1] = x;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", userArray[0], userArray[1], userArray[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers - your code doesn't take into account all 6 possibilities in which the values could be ordered.

A possible way to fix this: first, modify your "find maximum" function so it returns an index instead of a value:

```
int findBig(int d, int e, int f) {
    if ((d >= e) && (d >= f)) {
        return 0; // index of largest element is 0
    } else
    if ((e >= d) && (e >= f)) {
        return 1; // index of largest element is 1
    } else
    if ((f >= e) && (f >= d)) {
        return 2; // index of largest element is 2
    }
}
```

Then, find which number is big, small and median:

```
bigIndex = findBig(a, b, c);
smallIndex = findBig(-a, -b, -c); // a hack to find the minimum instead of maximum
if (bigIndex == smallIndex)
{
    // Edge case - all numbers are equal
    // Doesn't matter which index is which; just choose 3 different ones
    bigIndex = 0;
    midIndex = 1;
    smallIndex = 2;
}
else
{
    // Choose the index that is neither big nor small
    midIndex = 3 - bigIndex - smallIndex;
}
```

Then print them:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", userArray[smallIndex], userArray[midIndex], userArray[bigIndex]);
```

Here it helps that you have an array. Otherwise, it would still be possible to convert an index to a value bit it would be ugly:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",
    smallIndex == 0 ? a : smallIndex == 1 ? b : c,
    midIndex == 0 ? a : midIndex == 1 ? b : c,
    bigIndex == 0 ? a : bigIndex == 1 ? b : c);
```